Finding a well-spaced interval of natural numbers
For $b>0$, let us say that a subset $I\subseteq \{1,\ldots,n\}$ is $b$-good if
(1) $\# I\geq b n$,
(2) $\ell_{i+1}-\ell_i\leq \frac{1}{b}$ for all $i=1,\ldots,\#I-1$, where we write $I=\{\ell_i\}_{i=1}^{\# I}$ with $\ell_i<\ell_{i+1}$.
Question: Fix $a>0$. Does there always exist a $b=b(a)>0$ such that for all $n\geq 1$ and every $A\subseteq \{1,\ldots,n\}$ with $\#A\geq an$, there is some $b$-good subset $I\subseteq A$?
I cannot really trust my own intuition as combinatorics is not really my forte, and I was unable to come up with a proof nor a counter example.
Thanks in advance to all the helpers.

Okay, I edited to make the question clearer (and upvoted!). Let me know if this edit fails to captures your intended meaning in some way.

Thanks @SamHopkins, indeed it captures the original intention. Hopefully the clearer formulation helps getting an answer quicker.

@SamHopkins Hopefully it is true. I have some progress along those lines, but no proof.

The first step I took is to notice that the set of points in $A$ which have distance to their successive bounded by $\frac{1}{a^2}$, is larger than $(a-a^2)n$. So now the question is can I find a sufficiently long “interval” within them, without holes.

Won't $A := [1,bn-1] \cup [bn-1+\frac{1}{b},2bn-2+\frac{1}{b}] \cup [2bn-2+\frac{2}{b}, 3bn-3+\frac{2}{b}] \cup \dots$ have $|A| = n-O_b(1)$ and no $b$-good subset?

If $A$ contains $[1,bn-1]={1,\ldots ,bn-1}$, then it contains a $(b-\delta)$-good set, for all $\delta>0$, for all $n$ large enough w.r.t $\delta$.

The point is that @mathworker21's construction works to show that for any $a < 1$, the answer is: no, there is no such a $b$. For suppose there were such a $b$. Then form the set $A$ they wrote down; for $n$ sufficiently large it will have $#A\geq an$ but no $b$-good subset.

Oh I see! Indeed it shows such a general statement cannot hold, even if $\frac{1}{\beta}$ is replaced another function of $\beta$. Thanks!
